# Constraining the search

Tags: search, crawling, search-results

I did research on this topic, but i still have some unclear idea, that is why i'm creating this topic. This question concerning the search.
Is it possible to deactivate indexation of some lists on the webapplication, so that the lists will not appear in the search?
Maybe it might be not only lists, but for example some other parts of the intranet.

Honestly i don't know if it is possible.

And is it maybe easier to create some predefiened search scopes and apply them to the search center?
With search scopes i would be able to only display the needed information, and filter the unneeded.

Or is it still better to somehow deactivate the indexing on particular items, which are not desired to be searched in?
And if it is so, when i remove indexing on the lists, will they never be in the results anymore? Should i then do "Reset Indexes" in the central admin?

Or should i use the content sources?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

To exclude a list from search go to List Settings => Advanced Settings and set " Allow items from this list to appear in search results?" to no.

I'm not sure if an incremental crawl will remove it or you have do either:

- A full crawl
- Specify the URL of the items in Search Result Removal (below "Queries and Results" on left side in Search Administration for your search service application)

You can also remove items from search using Crawl Rules

Comment: I just need to make it standard, so just on the next search, ppl would not get results from some parts of the website, but only from for example FAQ etc etc, but not from some lists. I thought it wouuld be easier to do it with scopes, but is there a better way?

Comment: What I specified will remove the items from all searches. If you want to create a scope so that people/pages/tabs can target their search to a limited area, but still be able to expand to all items other places, the setting up a scope is a good solution.